# Jquery prepend with no class input=TYPE

Tags: jquery, radio-button, prepend

I am wondering if its possible to use a selector of an input field with no class... 
I do have quite a few options to use below is a psudo type command that I would like to accomplish.

Type of Command:

```
$("input[type=radio]").prepend("<br/>");
```

Current HTML:

```
<input type="radio">SelectME
```

Result Required:

```
<input type="radio">SelectME<BR/>
```

OR

```
<BR/><input type="radio">SelectME
```

Note: This document is acctually being loaded from another script, so the tag that I want to munipulate is inside a dynamically loaded object.

thats all that shows up in php file aside from the script to load it in the head. The input box is loaded within the IDX div, so I am having problems putting that BR in for mobile users...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep track of those quotes :

```
$('input[type="radio"]')
```

and you can't append or prepend to an input, it's self closing.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').before('<br />')
```

Comment: I am sure that you are correct sorry about the quote mistake - however... its still not working, see the added details on the question.

Comment: If the elements are dynamic, you'll have to wait until they are loaded, and the ajax function probably has a callback function for that. Also, the code above should be inside a document ready function etc.